# How to decode a extracted pfd file from a website in python?

Tags: python, pdf

Here is code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import codecs
import urllib.request
resp = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://normanpd.normanok.gov/filebrowser_download/657/2017-02-16%20Daily%20Incident%20Summary.pdf', 'test.pdf')
with codecs.open("test.pdf") as f:
     for line in f:
         line.decode('utf-8')

         print(line)
```

after executing the above code, i am getting an error as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "normanpd.py", line 6, in <module>
    for line in f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Kindly help me to get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think the file is an encoded string? It's not a string at all; a pdf is not readable, it's a binary format. You can't just iterate through and print it out.